# Laurent series of $(z-3)\sin\frac{1}{z+2}$ at $z=-2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, laurent-series

this is what I got

$f(z)=(z-3)\sin\frac{1}{z+2}=(z-3)\left(\frac{1}{z+2}-\frac{1}{3!}\left(\frac{1}{z+2}\right)^3+\frac{1}{5!}\left(\frac{1}{z+2}\right)^5+...\right)$
 $=(z+2)\left(\frac{1}{z+2}-\frac{1}{3!}\left(\frac{1}{z+2}\right)^3+\frac{1}{5!}\left(\frac{1}{z+2}\right)^5+...\right)-5\left(\frac{1}{z+2}-\frac{1}{3!}\left(\frac{1}{z+2}\right)^3+\frac{1}{5!}\left(\frac{1}{z+2}\right)^5+...\right)$
 $=1-\frac{5}{z+2}-\frac{1}{3!}\left(\frac{1}{z+2}\right)^2+\frac{5}{3!}\left(\frac{1}{z+2}\right)^3+\frac{1}{5!}\left(\frac{1}{z+2}\right)^4-\frac{5}{5!}\left(\frac{1}{z+2}\right)^5+...$

My question is how can I write the above sum in terms of a series?

Comment: You just did that. What more is there to say?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I mean how to write it in terms of a $\sum$.

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^0a_n(z+2)^n$ with $\displaystyle a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{(1-n)!}$ if $n$ is even and $\displaystyle a_n=\frac{(-1)^n5}{(-n)!}$ if $n$ is odd.

Comment: $\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^0  \frac{\cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)-5 (n-1) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (2-n)}   (z+2)^n $

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. One may write, for $|z+2|\ne0$,
$$
\begin{align}
(z-3)\sin\frac{1}{z+2}&=((z+2)-5)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!\left(z+2\right)^{2n+1}}
\\\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!\left(z+2\right)^{2n}}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{5(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!\left(z+2\right)^{2n+1}}
\\\\&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{\cos \frac{m\pi}{2}+5(m+1)\sin \frac{m\pi}{2}}{(m+1)!\left(z+2\right)^{m}}.
\end{align}
$$